# Store expressions for reusing it in a notebook with evaluation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have a conducted trigonometric manupulations to solve the geometry relations of a mechanism. For this purpose, i use a lot the FullSimplify function. This function makes for me very good simplifications. But, this function is very long. My code lasts 45 min. This is thus not all convenient to work of it.

A idea is to store the expressions which result from the simplifications so that i needn't to reevaluate it each time.

How can i do to store expressions in a notebook so that i could them directly with reevaluating all my notebook ?

Thanks you for you tips.

Comment: `Export[]`,`Import[]`?

Comment: May be but can you develop a little bit more with a short example ?

Comment: Simply store the result in a variable. `a=FullSimplify[]`,`Export["name.txt",a]`. Then you can import with `a=Import["name.txt"]`

Comment: Look up `Save[]` and `DumpSave[]`.  And `Get[]`.

Comment: I suggest you read the Documentation Center article [PersistentStorage](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PersistentStorage.html)

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I experimented a bit more these functions. In fact, Save[] and Get[] seem not to be very appropriated for my need because it saves not all the definition leading to a symbol. Consequently, Import / Export seems more appropriated since i can export the results as an expression without all the definitions

Answer (score 4):

```
y = Simplify[{Sin[x]/Cos[x], 1 - Tanh[x]^2}]
```

> $\left\{\tan (x),\text{sech}^2(x)\right\}$

```
Export["expr1.m", y]
```

> expr1.m

```
y1 = Import["expr1.m"]
Plot[y1, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> $\left\{\tan (x),\text{sech}^2(x)\right\}$

[image]

you can open and check `expr1.m` for your expressions.